# Oracle CTE query: datatype error ORA-00932

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, recursive-query

I'm trying a following CTE query in Oralce 11g, but I get an error saying

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR.

Any ideas what is the root cause of this?

```
create table PC (
EMP_ID NUMBER NULL,
MGR_ID NUMBER NULL
);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (1.0, NULL);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (2.0, 1.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (3.0, 1.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (4.0, 2.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (5.0, 2.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (6.0, 2.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (7.0, 3.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (8.0, 5.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (9.0, 7.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (10.0, 5.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (11.0, 7.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (12.0, 9.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (13.0, 9.0);

INSERT INTO PC (EMP_ID, MGR_ID) 
VALUES (14.0, 9.0);

SELECT * FROM pc;

with  Tree (EMP_ID, MGR_ID, lv, level1, level2, level3, level4, level5) as
        (
        SELECT  EMP_ID
        ,       MGR_ID
        ,       1 as lv
        ,       1 as level1
        ,       null as level2
        ,       null as level3
        ,       null as level4
        ,       null as level5
        FROM    PC
        WHERE   MGR_ID IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  E.EMP_ID
        ,       E.MGR_ID
        ,       T.lv + 1
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 1 then E.EMP_ID else T.level1 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 2 then E.EMP_ID else T.level2 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 3 then E.EMP_ID else T.level3 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 4 then E.EMP_ID else T.level4 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 5 then E.EMP_ID else T.level5 end
        FROM    Tree T inner join PC E
                ON      (T.EMP_ID = E.MGR_ID)
        )
select  *
from    Tree
```

Comment: Do you want those initial values of `level1`, etc to be null? It looks like the query works if you change those to 0 see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dac35/1

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem, can you make this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You can also use "cast (null as number) as level2" etc

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that! I think that is even better solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your first part of the query to use zeros as the values for `level1`, etc instead of `null` the query will work:

```
with  Tree (EMP_ID, MGR_ID, lv, level1, level2, level3, level4, level5) as
        (
        SELECT  EMP_ID
        ,       MGR_ID
        ,       1 as lv
        ,       1 as level1
        ,       0 as level2
        ,       0 as level3
        ,       0 as level4
        ,       0 as level5
        FROM    PC
        WHERE   MGR_ID IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  E.EMP_ID
        ,       E.MGR_ID
        ,       T.lv + 1
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 1 then E.EMP_ID else T.level1 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 2 then E.EMP_ID else T.level2 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 3 then E.EMP_ID else T.level3 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 4 then E.EMP_ID else T.level4 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 5 then E.EMP_ID else T.level5 end
        FROM    Tree T inner join PC E
                ON      (T.EMP_ID = E.MGR_ID)
        )
select  *
from    Tree
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dac35/1)

Result:

```
| EMP_ID | MGR_ID | LV | LEVEL1 | LEVEL2 | LEVEL3 | LEVEL4 | LEVEL5 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1 | (null) |  1 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
|      2 |      1 |  2 |      1 |      2 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
|      3 |      1 |  2 |      1 |      3 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
|      4 |      2 |  3 |      1 |      2 |      4 |      0 |      0 |
|      5 |      2 |  3 |      1 |      2 |      5 |      0 |      0 |
|      6 |      2 |  3 |      1 |      2 |      6 |      0 |      0 |
|      7 |      3 |  3 |      1 |      3 |      7 |      0 |      0 |
|      8 |      5 |  4 |      1 |      2 |      5 |      8 |      0 |
|      9 |      7 |  4 |      1 |      3 |      7 |      9 |      0 |
|     10 |      5 |  4 |      1 |      2 |      5 |     10 |      0 |
|     11 |      7 |  4 |      1 |      3 |      7 |     11 |      0 |
|     12 |      9 |  5 |      1 |      3 |      7 |      9 |     12 |
|     13 |      9 |  5 |      1 |      3 |      7 |      9 |     13 |
|     14 |      9 |  5 |      1 |      3 |      7 |      9 |     14 |
```

Or you can `cast(null as number)` and the query will work:

```
with  Tree (EMP_ID, MGR_ID, lv, level1, level2, level3, level4, level5) as
        (
        SELECT  EMP_ID
        ,       MGR_ID
        ,       1 as lv
        ,       1 as level1
        ,       cast(null as number) as level2
        ,       cast(null as number) as level3
        ,       cast(null as number) as level4
        ,       cast(null as number) as level5
        FROM    PC
        WHERE   MGR_ID IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  E.EMP_ID
        ,       E.MGR_ID
        ,       T.lv + 1
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 1 then E.EMP_ID else T.level1 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 2 then E.EMP_ID else T.level2 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 3 then E.EMP_ID else T.level3 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 4 then E.EMP_ID else T.level4 end
        ,       case when T.lv + 1 = 5 then E.EMP_ID else T.level5 end
        FROM    Tree T inner join PC E
                ON      (T.EMP_ID = E.MGR_ID)
        )
select  *
from    Tree
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dac35/3)